# Data structure to store 2D-arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

i am looking for a data structure to store two dimensional integer arrays.
Is List the rigth data structure or should i use another one?

Can someone give me a short example on how to create such a data structure and how to add a 2d array?

Edit: I want a data structure in which i want to store int[11][7] arrays.
For instance ten, int[11][7] arrays.

Comment: You could use List<List<Integer>>, or... what about int[][] ?

Comment: what are your requirements around the data structure ? A 2D array is itself a data structure , so what are you looking to wrap this into and why ?

Comment: A lot of data structures will hold 2D arrays, but what **other** requirements you have are the more important details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to store a number of `int[][]` arrays in a data structure, I would probably recommend that you store the `int[][]` arrays in an `Object` that represents what the data contains, then store these `Objects` in an `ArrayList`.

For example, here is a simple `Object` wrapper for your `int[][]` arrays

```
public class 2DArray {
    int[][] array;
    public 2DArray(int[][] initialArray){
        array = initialArray;
    }
}
```

And here is how you would use them, and store them in an `ArrayList`

```
// create the list
ArrayList<2DArray> myList = new ArrayList<2DArray>();
// add the 2D arrays to the list
myList.add(new 2DArray(myArray1));
myList.add(new 2DArray(myArray2));
myList.add(new 2DArray(myArray3));
```

The reason for my suggestion is that your `int[][]` array must have some meaning to you. By storing this in an `Object` wrapper class, you can give it a meaning. For example, if the values were co-ordinates, you would call your class `Coordinates` instead of `2DArray`. You, therefore, create a `List` of `Coordinates`, which has a lot more meaning than `int[][][]`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it this way and if cant make it work (as i've never used Lists before), i will try int[][][], as it's easier for me to understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Give it a try - `ArrayLists` are pretty simple - just have a look at the Java documentation for the list of methods. All array commands have an equivalent - for example, instead of calling `array[0]`, you call `list.get(0);`.

Answer (score 2):

An array is not just an idea about how to store information, it is also an implementation of how to store data.  Thus, if you use an array, you have already selected your data structure.

If you want to store data in a data structure, you need to concentrate on how the data structure is used, think about how you will retrieve data and store data, how often you do each operation, and how much data you will be working with.  Then you know which methods must be optimum, and have an idea of whether the data can reside in memory, etc.

Just to give you an example of how many ways this could be solved:

1. You could flatten the array into a 1D array, and use x*num_columns+y as the index
2. You could create an Object to contain the pair, and put the array in a Map
3. You could use a linked list containing linked lists.
4. You could use a tree containing trees.
5. You could use a list containing trees.
6. You could create a partial order over the pair and then put all the elements into one tree.

All of these solutions depend heavily on which operations are more important to optimize.  Sometime it is more important to update the data structure quickly, sometimes not.  The deciding factor is really the rest of your program.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to store a collection of 2D arrays: if the collection is fixed size add another dimension:

```
int[][][] arrColl
```

If the collection is variably sized, use your favorite implementation of `Collection<int[][]>` (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.):

```
Collection<int[][]> arrColl
```

Answer (score 0):

If size is fixed, then use `int[][]` else `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: The size of the 2d arrays is fixed. it is int[11][7].

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you need to have array of arrays. Than qou can use List<int[][]> or int[][][].

Answer (score 0):

based on your edits :

`List<Integer[][]>` is what you need - this will allow you to add any numbers of 2D `Integer` arrays. Note that this will involve boxing and unboxing - something that should be avoided if possible.

If it suffices ( if you know how many 2D int arrays you need in advance ), you can even use `int[][][]` - a 3D array of ints - this does not involve boxing/unboxing.