# Changing the name of a matrix through a loop

Tags: java, matrix

I think I could determine the answer to this question thank you anyway
    public class Matrix {

```
    private double[][] mat;

    public Matrix(double[][] mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    public double[][] getMatrix() {
        return mat;
    }

    public void setMatrix(double[][] mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }
```

Comment: Like `float[][] newArray = oldArray;`?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean change the name of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785760/data-structure-to-store-2d-arrays-in-java), you should create a class that holds the 2D array as a data structure. An example of this would be:

```
public class Matrix {

    private double[][] mat;

    public Matrix(double[][] mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    public double[][] getMatrix() {
        return mat;
    }

    public void setMatrix(double[][] mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }
```

And then for your code to make matrices with random floats/doubles would be like:

```
public static ArrayList<Matrix> generateMatrices(int num, int size) {
    ArrayList<Matrix> matrices = new ArrayList<Matrix>();

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        double[][] matrix = new double[size][size];
        //populate matrix with random numbers
        matrices.add(new Matrix(matrix));
    }
    return matrices;
}
```

And all you would do is call the method and get an ArrayList of matrices:

```
ArrayList<Matrix> generated = generateMatrices(10, 5);
```

Hopefully this helped.

Edit:

toString() is a method all Object classes have. If you try printing out an Object, it will use the Object's toString method(). The toString() method primitively returns the memory location of the object instance. Some objects, like the ArrayList class, override the method already in order for programmers to print it out easily. You must override the toString() method in order to print out your Matrix class, specifically being the matrix stored in its class. You could make a custom method that prints it out, but instead I've decided to show you a small part of OOP. In your Matrix class, add this piece of code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    stringedMat = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
            if(j != (mat.length - 1)) {
                stringedMat += (mat[i][j] + " ");
            }else{
                stringedMat += mat[i][j];
            }
        }
        stringedMat += "\n";
    }

    return stringedMat;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I tried to print generated System.out.println(generated); I got the name of my package which is (com.example.mymatrixtest).Matrix@7852e922 and I got these ten times [com.example.mymatrixtest.Matrix@7852e922,

Comment: That is because you need to override the toString() method. I updated the post so you can understand it. toString() is a method that all Object classes have for the sole purpose to override and return something useful that "sums" up the object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but my problem is bigger than this I have updated my original post to explain the problem in more detail thank you again

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution could be to use a three-dimensional array instead, with the first index being `chckNumberOfMatrix` for instance. That way you have an "array of 2d matrices", each with a name (that is, they're all called `H[0]`, `H[1]`, and so on.)